# event.preventDefault() doesn't work in on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I want to stop the event click.

I try to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop event on "ul li a".

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click','ul li a', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).on('click','ul li a', function(event){
        alert('Thank you for clicking');
    });
});
</script>
```

But when I click on "ul li a", it should show nothing, but it shows `alert('Thank you for clicking')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event's default action (redirecting you to another page, if the `a` had a proper `href`) *does* successfully get prevented. But calling `preventDefault` does not prevent *other* handlers for the event from being triggered. If you want to prevent a later handler from running when it's attached to the same element (`document`, here), use `stopImmediatePropagation`:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'ul li a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$(document).on('click', 'ul li a', function(event) {
  alert('Thank you for clicking');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>
</ul>
```

If the handler that you want to prevent is attached to a parent element, use `stopPropagation` instead. If the handler that you want to prevent is attached to a child element, use `stopPropagation` *and* have the initial handler run in the capturing phase:

```js
ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('ul li a')) {
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}, true);

$(document).on('click', 'li a', function(event) {
  alert('Thank you for clicking');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul">
  <li><a href="#">Click here</a></li>
</ul>
```

If the `a` will always have a `href` of `#`, then `preventDefault` is not needed, because the page won't be changed regardless.

Comment: Thank you. I checked if I use stopImmediatePropagation, I don't need preventDefault. Is that right?

Comment: No, they do entirely different things. If your links all have a `href` of `#`, then there's no need for `preventDefault` regardless - what `preventDefault` does is it prevents the page from being replaced. `stopImmediatePropagation` stops the event from propagating to other handlers *attached to the same element*. `stopPropagation` stops the event from propagating to *other elements* in the capturing/bubbling phase.

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: I want to upvote your answer and Accepted but I can't. So I just accepted it. Thank you :)